# Eclipse not having run as java applet application

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

I setup my eclipse for PROCESSING perfectely..
I am using Eclipse Oxygen and installed PROCESSING 3.3.6
i am trying to run processing program in eclipse and there is no option is run as Applet
My code is below :

package processing01;

```
    import processing.core.PApplet;

    public class Processing01 extends PApplet{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    PApplet.main("Processing01");
    }
    public void settings(){
        size(300,300);
    }

    public void setup(){
        fill(120,50,240);
    }

    public void draw(){
        ellipse(width/2,height/2,second(),second());
    }

    }
```

Comment: don't you see any option called "run as application" or something similar ?

Comment: yes only run as java application

Answer (score 1):

Processing 3 no longer supports running as an applet. From [the Processing 3 change list](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Changes-in-3.0):

> **Applet is gone** — Java's `java.awt.Applet` is no longer the base class used by `PApplet`, so any sketches that make use of Applet-specific methods (or assume that a `PApplet` is a Java AWT Component object) will need to be rewritten.

The `PApplet` class no longer extends the `Applet` class, which means you can't treat Processing sketches as a component anymore, and you can't run them as an applet. You can only run them as an application.

Applets are dead, and shouldn't be used anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Because having package the code would be

```
                   //replace
      PApplet.main("Processing01");
                   //with
      PApplet.main("processing01.Processing01");
```